# How to resolve "project creation failed" InstallShield issue in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I am trying to import and setup existing project into Visual Studio 2013, the project has dependency for InstallShield.

Below is the link I am refering to enable InstallShield :

[How to enable InstallShield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn531020(v=vs.120).aspx)

But all the efforts are going in vain as its throwing below error :

```
"Creating project 'Setup6'... project creation failed."
```

Attaching the screenshots for better understanding of the issue.

[image]

[image]

Note : My ultimate goal is to import the project, due to this problem i am not able to import the project and facing incompatibility issues.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to enable it , the visual studio opened web browser with this link:
http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio?lang=1033&ver=ultimate